Intent to update all on google play store?
com.google.android.finsky.VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS with Package as com.android.vending gets to the overview page.
It was remarked on a reddit thread about 10 years ago that Extra "trigger_update_all:true" would update all, but that does nothing now.
I opened the manifest, but found nothing. Any ideas?
